# Build hint to expand notifications or use notification groups with CodenameOne Push Messages

Tags: android, push-notification, codenameone

I was wondering if there was a way to expand push notifications on Android devices generated by our server to mimic the behavior in the 2nd image, as [seen here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group), via build hints.

What I noticed is that if I send multiple push messages from our server, the messages are in that "collapsed" mode, and it's not possible to click each individual message. This is especially important because I'd like to set different push behaviors based on the type of push message. For example, a type 1 message is dealt with 1 way in the app and a type 3 with JSON is handled in a different way.

Is there a build hint to accomplish this? I already added the build hints from [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/codenameone-discussions/0R35RIqB8yk/pMDlir0oAQAJ) to my `.properties` file but that didn't seem to address this issue:

```
android.NotificationChannel.id = my app channel
android.NotificationChannel.name = my app channel
android.NotificationChannel.importance = 4
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately CN1's Android push currently groups n+1 notifications in a way that prevents this.

If you want to acomplish this you will have to write your own push implementation from scratch. I wrote a tutorial on how to do this [here](https://collaborativegroups.blogspot.com/2020/05/implementing-native-android-ios-push-in.html)